# Implementing a client for custom TCP protocol

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, protocols

I have to implement a client for communication with the server by custom protocol based on `XML` format. This is an application layer protocol, based on `TCP`. So, my client sends a request `XML` message and receives a response, also XML message. Now, I consider how to be ensured that I received whole mesage before I start parsing it.

I see two aproaches:

1. Receiving bytes to the some magic number that means end of message. 
   It is the best approch (for my eye), yes?
2. But, it is possible that there is no magic number and size of message is not known. What about that case? I saw some clients for other protocols and I see something like that.

   ```
   while(true){
       r = socket.read(buffer, offset, 1024);
       if(r < 1024) break;
       offset += r;
   }
   // parse buffer
   ```

and I am not sure whether it is ok. It assumes that if we read less than 1024 bytes then the messae is completed. Is it ok?

What is a recommend way to solve it?

Comment: That is not a custom tcp protocol. You're simply reading from a ``Socket``'s ``InputStream``. Take a look at what the different ``read`` methods do.

Comment: If you can control the spec to add magic numbers, why not just switch to Rest?  Its basic form is XML based, you'd likely have few changes, and the whole problem you have now would just disappear.  (But likely what you want to do is read until end of stream.)

Comment: EDIT: but the loop of code you show above is dead wrong.  Please use Google and find something better.

Comment: take advice from http (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.3.3) - have the client send the length of the content before the content itself

Answer (score 0):

In your custom protocol you need to include the steps below :

**Client**

1. Calculate number of 1024 byte chunks of the XML contents i.e *ceiling(XML content bytes /1024)*
2. Send the number of step 1 to the server through the socket
3. Transmit the contents in chunks of a defined buffer size e.g 1024 bytes

**Server**

1. Read number of chunks to receive from client
2. Inside a for loop of size equal to the number read at step 1, start receiving contents in the predifined buffer size.

This way the server knows how many bytes the actual content is before it starts receiving the XML contents.

Comment: I know how TCP works...what part indicates the opposite?

Comment: Even if you send 1024 byte in every packet, the operating system can send it in many TCP segments. From

Comment: Please note that your post is not answer. I am implementing a **client**. Not a server.

Comment: In your question you write...."I have to implement a client **for communication with the server** by **custom protocol** based on XML format". You can't be implementing only the client unless you already know how the receiving end (server) operates. Then it is not a protocol....it is a client!  If it is a protocol and in the application layer as you say...it uses TCP and the segments are send and received correctly by the use of java sockets. Your only concern is the contents of the message. So before you start insulting others please read carefully the answers and the question you posted!

Comment: I have to **implement a client** for communication with the server.

Comment: Then it should be useful to provide the way the server functions, since your client depends on it.

Comment: In order to know you received the message you should transmit it's size before it's contents....as in the TCP protocol a segment contains a  header....in your protocol the first bytes you send should include the size of the contents and the options of your protocol....in order for the server to know how many bytes to receive, and also a starting point equivalent to the data offset of the TCP segment.