# How to close the connection to return a Mono<byte[]> while using Reactive Netty connect() without blocking?

Tags: spring-webflux, reactive-programming, reactor-netty

I am creating an application that receives http requests and requires to connect with a tcp server to get the response. At the rest controller, I am returning a Mono<byte[]>.

In the service class, I am unable to properly return a Mono<byte[]> to the controller and I suspect it is because the connection is not closed. With the below code, I am unable to close the connection at any point

`TcpClient().create().host(host).port(port).connect().flatMap(conn -> conn.outbound().sendByteArray(...).then().thenMany(conn.inbound().receive().asByteArray().log().single());`

With this code, I am able to see the response received and being logged onNext() but onComplete() is not called so the http request will time out

Would anyone be able to suggest how we can do this in a non blocking fashion for tcp? Similar to implementations done with reactive mongo: e.g. https://wearecommunity.io/communities/jacov/articles/2496

Errors I faced:

1. connectNow is a blocking operation which is not supported
2. source was empty

---

EDIT:

```
TcpClient
.create()
.host("host")
.port("port")
.connect() // to produce a Mono<Connection>
.flatmap(conn -> {
     Mono<byte[]> single = conn.outbound().sendByteArray(...).then().thenMany(conn.inbound().receive.asByteArray()).single();
     conn.dispose()
     return single; // convert flux to mono

}); // return Mono<byte[]>
```

Comment: what is connectNow , have you defined a method ?

Comment: No that is the method given in the builder

Comment: This is a TCP connection - you send and receive packages unless the connection is closed by one of the peers. If the server does not close the connection you cannot receive `onComplete`. This is not HTTP, I don't know you may have some protocol of your own (you didn't mention)

Comment: If the server does not close the connection you cannot receive onComplete -> does this mean that the system that we are connecting to needs to close the connection after sending the response? or we have to explicitly close? I have not implemented any protocols

Comment: You have either close the connection or have some protocol that tells you when the response is done.

Comment: what kind of protocols can tell us that the response from the server is complete? can this be implemented on the client side or does the server need to send some sort of indication?

Comment: Both the server and the client need to understand the protocol, so that they know the start and the end.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48192158/implementing-a-client-for-custom-tcp-protocol --> Based on this, I can identify that the response is complete using the byte array size. I have updated the question with the code. Could you suggest where exactly can we implement the check to close the connection on client side instead of server?